# Sorting and Filtering Data - Flutter - Realtime Database

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have continuing data like this in my firebase realtime database. I want to get keys with values ​​greater than 75, their values and Province value.

```
  {
    "allboxes": {
      "box00001": {
        "boxes": {
          "Electronic Box": 80,
          "Glass Box": 25,
          "Metal Box": 78,
          "Oil Box": 90,
          "Paper Box": 77,
          "Plastic Box": 18
        },
        "info": {
          "Id": "00001",
          "Province": "Keçiören"
        }
      },
      "box00002": {
        "boxes": {
          "Electronic Box": 95,
          "Glass Box": 86,
          "Metal Box": 45,
          "Oil Box": 79,
          "Paper Box": 98,
          "Plastic Box": 18
        },
        "info": {
          "Id": "00002",
          "Province": "Etimesgut"
        }
      },
      "box00003": {
        "boxes": {
          "Electronic Box": 55,
          "Glass Box": 91,
          "Metal Box": 79,
          "Oil Box": 65,
          "Paper Box": 50,
          "Plastic Box": 100
        },
        "info": {
          "Id": "00003",
          "Province": "Çankaya"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I will use it in a Gridview.builder like this;

```
 GridView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    gridDelegate:
        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      mainAxisExtent: 220,
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      crossAxisSpacing: 15,
    ),
    itemCount: boxesValuesList!.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => OpenedBoxesGrid(
      boxesValuesList![index].toString(),
      boxesKeysList![index],
      provinceValuesList![index],
    ),
  )
```

I tried this;

```
  final greaterThan75ValueTaskRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance
  .ref('allboxes')
  .orderByChild('boxes/Oil Box')
  .startAt(75);
```

And It returns this in print function.

> I/flutter ( 6345): [{boxes: {Glass Box: 86, Plastic Box: 18, Electronic Box: 95, Metal Box: 45, Oil Box: 79, Paper Box: 98}, info: {Id: 00002, Province: Etimesgut}}, {boxes: {Glass Box: 25, Plastic Box: 18, Electronic Box: 80, Metal Box: 78, Oil Box: 90, Paper Box: 77}, info: {Id: 00001, Province: Keçiören}}]

But as I mentioned, I want to get keys in one list, their values in another list, and their province values in another list. How can I do that? I want to create three lists with the ordered equivalent of each element like this.

> [Electronic Box, Metal Box, Oil Box, Paper Box, Electronic Box, Glass Box, Oil Box, Paper Box, Glass Box, Metal Box, Plastic Box]

> [80, 78, 90, 77, 95, 86, 79, 98, 91, 79, 100]

> [Keçiören, Keçiören, Keçiören, Keçiören, Etimesgut, Etimesgut, Etimesgut, Etimesgut, Çankaya, Çankaya, Çankaya]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Is the order in the print output not what you expect? If so: can you edit your question to show exactly how you get that print output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read from the Firebase Realtime Database, you get a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot-class.html) with all the data from the path that you read.

To get the key of a snapshot, call its [`key` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DataSnapshot/key.html).

To get just the a specific branch under the snapshot, use its `child()` method. So for example (assuming that `boxesValuesList` is the `DataSnapshot` with the result of the query you shared), to get a snapshot of just the boxes in your builder, you'd do `boxesValuesList![index].child("boxes")`.

This can go multiple levels deep, so again assuming that `boxesValuesList` is the `DataSnapshot` with the result of the query you shared, you could get just the value of the Oilbox with: `boxesValuesList![index].child("boxes").child("Oil Box").getValue()` or with a shorthand notation: `boxesValuesList![index].child("boxes/Oil Box").getValue()`.